# How to show a content panel when user clicks on the mail which is inside grid which is inside tab panel

Tags: extjs

I have to show the content panel of the mail when user clicks on the mail which is inside the grid and grid is inside tab panel.Problem is I don't know how to  show my content panel.

I can already show the content panel if only grid panel is present.Problem occurs if tab panel comes in the picture.

```
 onGridCellItemClick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record){
      if(cellIndex > 1){
          this.setCurrentView('emaildetails', {record: record});
             } else if (cellIndex === 1) {
              //Invert selection
             record.set('favorite', !record.get('favorite'));
                }
            },
```

This is my controller code when cell click is inside grid panel.

what  to write in controller logic if cell click is inside grid panel which is inside tab panel.

i have already tried hide method but no help.

```
    onGridCellItemClick2: function(grid, record, item, index) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Info',`You have clicked on ${index+1} item`);
    this.setCurrentView('emaildetails', {record: record});

//      if (index === 1) {
//         //Invert selection
//         record.set('favorite', !record.get('favorite'));
//         }
       },
```

this is my logic for if cell click is inside grid panel which is inside tab panel.

Comment: So, you have a tab panel with a grid inside, and you want to change tab's?

Comment: No,i want to change the tab panel with my content panel.It's like gmail having tab panel with tabs of primary,social ,promotion and when we click on a particular mail in grid panel it opens it that's my content panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using the [card](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.Card.html) layout and when that specific cell is clicked switch between panels using the **setActiveItem()** function.

Comment: I cannot change my layout as it is already working in case of grid panel.Can you give me a solution if tab panel is also there or may be you can help me with an example

Comment: It does not matter if the grid is inside a tabpanel or not. You just have to create an intermediate panel. 
The structure should be like this: you have your tabpanel than has a child that is the intermediate panel (with layout card), and this panel has 2 children: your grid and your email details

Comment: Hey followed your solution and created the panel...thanks.However I'm stuck in switching between panels.Can you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967758/how-to-switch-between-cards-in-card-layout