# How to switch panels in card layout

Tags: extjs

I have a card layout having two cards one with tab panel.Inside tab panel grid panel is there and another card is my content panel. I have to switch to next card i.e my content panel on cell click on my grid panel.

Comment: What have you done ? Where is the problem ? Can you attach a minimal reproductible example?

Comment: This is my question with full details. Can you please give it a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967758/how-to-switch-between-cards-in-card-layout